# VBA Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to connect to a webpage and enter a value but it's giving me the runtime error as follows:

> `Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'.`

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub OpenMyURL()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
myjobtype = InputBox("Enter offer name")
With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "visualreports.aexp.com/#/views/AmexOffersPersistenceReport/…; 'getting runtime error here "
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set what = objIE.document.getElementsByName("omniboxTextBox")
    what.Item(0).Value = myjobtype
    .document.getElementById("JobsButton").Click
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub OpenMyURL()



Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
myjobtype = InputBox("Enter offer name")
With objIE
.Visible = True
.navigate "https://visualreports.aexp.com/#/views/AmexOffersPersistenceReport/AmexOffers?:iid=1"
'getting runtime error here
Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set what = objIE.document.getElementsByName("omniboxTextBox")
what.Item(0).Value = myjobtype
.document.getElementById("JobsButton").Click
Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Please use the edit link beneath your question and add the code into the question itself.  It is completely unreadable in comments.

Comment: Not able to add my code while clicking the edit button